# Grails mapping issue - many to many

Tags: hibernate, grails, data-modeling, grails-orm

I have following structure

```
class User{
  List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
  static hasMany = [posts: Post]
}
```

---

```
   class Post{
     User user  
     List<User> subscribers = new ArrayList<User>();
     static belongsTo = [user: User]
     static hasMany = [subscribers: User]
   }
```

and it shows

> Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: No owner
>   defined between domain classes [class User] and [class Post] in a
>   many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = Post

- A user can have multiple post
- A Post belongs to a User
- A Post can have multiple subscribers

Version Grails **1.3.7**

Comment: please don't comment on fetching all the posts at a time

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, meaning creating a many to many relationship AND a 1 to many relationship between the same two classes.

The way to do that is as following:

**User class:**

```
class User{

  static hasMany = [createdPosts: Post, subscribedToPosts : Post]
  static mappedBy = [createdPosts : "creator"]
}
```

**Post class:**

```
class Post{  

  User creator
  static hasMany = [subscribers: User]
  static belongsTo = User
}
```

I've found that answer in [this discussion](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/One-to-many-and-many-to-many-in-the-same-tables-td1386071.html)

Comment: yep, that answer should fix it. 
also note that this is (vaguely) mentioned in the docs http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html